# How to retrieve the Sharepoint Farm Library Document ID to the infopath form immediately after the Infopath form submission?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

In my infopath I have 2 views. Creation and Read-Only.
Once the user creates a form through the Creation view and clicks on Submit button, I need to fetch the sharepoint id for the document in Farm library and display in the read-only view. Please suggest in fetching the Sharepoint Id.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

See this post, I believe it will answer your question.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/689e681f-d46a-4621-a0cf-55fd49a0432a/i-want-to-display-the-id-of-an-infopath-form-after-submission-to-a-doc-library-on-sharepoint?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy